# Вывести данные из массива в EditText Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin

всем привет! как вывести данные из массива в Edit text.  у меня например цифра 4 у него индекс 0. мне нужно вывести этот массив 45 в editText на котлине , можете пожалуйста показать как выводить пожалуйста на котлине , у меня не получается . спасибо

```
val massiv = arrayOf(4,45,234,234,23)

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)


    val Edmassiv1 = findViewById<EditText>(R.id.Edmassiv1)
    
    Edmassiv1.text = massiv[0].toString()

}
```

}

Comment: Andrew простите я не понял

Comment: я добавил ответ, посмотрите пожалуйста, это то что вам нужно, или я все-таки не понял ваш вопрос?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если я правильно понял то вам нужно вывести весь массив в поле для ввода а не только одно значение. Для таких целей можно использовать функцию `.append()`. Делается это так:

```
Edmassiv1.text = massiv[0].toString()
for (i in 1 until massiv.size){
Edmassiv1.append(massiv[i].toString())
}
```

но таким образом у вас будет текст без разделения на элементы массива, поэтому стоит добавить какие-то пробелы вначале добавляемой строки:

```
Edmassiv1.append(" " + massiv[i].toString())
```

получится что-то вроде:

```
4 45 234 234 23
```

### UPDATE

Как мне уже указали из комментария, хотя я за этот метод не знал, можно использовать [joinToString()](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/join-to-string.html), например так:

```
Edmassiv1.text = massiv.joinToString(separator = " ")
```

Comment: да вышло спасибо вам большое!

Comment: это делается проще без циклов с помощью функции .joinToString()

Comment: @Cypher, я про этот метод не слышал до того как вы не сказали)) спасибо :) отредактировал ответ с вашим методом тоже :)